# phpWord - Tables with borders in headers/footers

Tags: php, phpword

I am working with phpWord and bringing changes to the header/footer content gives me a real hard time. What I am trying is to have header content arranged in a table. The table is created through the code I write. But the styles I try to apply to the table placed in a header does not take effect.

Following is a part of my code in which I may be making a mistake.

```
$phpWordObj = new PhpWord();
    $section = $phpWordObj->addSection();

    $styleTable = array('borderSize' => 18, 'borderColor' => '006699');
    $phpWordObj->addTableStyle('My Custom Style', $styleTable);

    //ADD HEADER TO DOCUMENT
    $header = $section->addHeader();
    $header->firstPage();
    $table = $header->addTable();
    $table->addRow();
//logo
    $table->addCell(2000)->addImage(
        '../vendor/phpoffice/phpword/samples/resources/PhpWord.png',
        array('width' => 80, 'height' => 80, 'align' => 'left')
    ); //logo
    $cell = $table->addCell(7000);
    $textrun = $cell->addTextRun();
    $textrun->addText(htmlspecialchars('Custom Name goes here...'));

    $headerGen = $section->addHeader();
    $tableGenHeader = $headerGen->addTable();
    $tableGenHeader->addRow();
//logo
    $tableGenHeader->addCell(2000)->addImage(
        '../vendor/phpoffice/phpword/samples/resources/PhpWord.png',
        array('width' => 80, 'height' => 80, 'align' => 'left')
    );  
    $cellGenHeader = $tableGenHeader->addCell(7000);
    $textrunGenHeader = $cellGenHeader->addTextRun();
    $textrunGenHeader->addText(htmlspecialchars('Custom Name goes here...'));
```

All I want is borders to appear so that the header contents can be differentiated from each other.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The $phpWordObj->addTableStyle(...) adds a new table style that you need to reference in the table addition (i.e. it is not a global definition). Adding the style name as a parameter to your addTable calls should do the trick:

```
$table = $header->addTable('My Custom Style');
```

Comment: `$header->addTable(array(--my style parameters--));` did the trick. :-)